# Problem on performing CRUD operation using Django REST API

Tags: python, django

Hey I am new to Django Rest Framework.I have recently created REST API name "api/studentapi" using django REST framework in local host. The CRUD operation works perfectly fine in browseable API. But When I try to access the same API from third party python file, I am not able to perform POST operation although I am able to perform GET operation.While performing POST operation the server reponse me as "Unsupported Media Type: /api/studentapi/".I am posting series of code images so that the stuffs gets more clear
[The third party python app that I have created to access the "api/studentapi"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itRYN.jpg)

[The file structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k71LE.jpg)

[The model form that I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXrXN.jpg)

[The serializer files that I have created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GGaH.jpg)

[The urls code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8dO0.jpg)

[And Finally the view file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJOb.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you a passing the content type header during your post and put request, as that's how `django_rest_framework` understands which parser it will use. The Django rest framework supports content type of `form-data`,  `JSON`, `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart` out of the box.

If you're sending JSON data add the header to your request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

If you send form data or file(s) add the header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

If you're sending only form data use:

```
Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencoded
```

For your code this is how to add the header

```py
r = request.post(
    url=URL,
    data=json_data,
    headers= {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
You need to pass the payload as `json` argument in `requests.post`:

```
data = {
   "name": "sa",
   "roll": 1,
   "city": "lam"
}

r = requests.post(url=URL, json=data)
```

Details:

As stated in the official [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) of `requests` library:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

> Please note that the above code will NOT add the Content-Type header
> (so in particular it will NOT set it to application/json).
>
> If you need that header set and you don’t want to encode the dict
> yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter
> (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:

```
url = 'https://api.github.com/some/endpoint'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import requests
url = "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/studentapi/"
data_response = {
   "name": "sa",
   "roll": 1,
   "city": "lam"
}
data_json =  json.dumps(data_response)
req =  requests.post(url, data=data_json)
```